# Finding Percentage Contribution of a Variable in an Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I have an equation, for example:

$$
y=a-b+c
$$
I am actually confused how exactly to find the contribution of the variables individually to the entire equation. Due to the negative sign, following $\frac a{a-b+c}$ sometimes gives percentage higher than 100%, which kinda violates the rule. Is there a better or a more appropriate method to find the individual contribution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What rule are you talking about?  Assuming $a,b,c,y$ are all positive, it can be that $a \gt y$, so $\frac ay \gt 100\%$  The contribution from $b$ will be negative and the contributions of the three will add to $100\%$

Comment: the rule im talking about is that the percentage contribution musn't exceed 100%. or is there another way to gage individual variables' contribution?

Comment: If something has a negative contribution, the others have to make up for it somewhere.